# Get transaction list of inAppPurchases on iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins, in-app-billing

Do the api's provided by Apple and Google make it possible for an app coder to get a list of all transactions for all users for an inapppurchase, or a list of all approved transactions?

Similarly, is it possible to get a list of all paying users who have made an inapppurchase?

Ideally, it would be great to do this without having to write native code (eg either using a cordova plugin or querying the app store using an http-based api).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an sdk/backend that is designed for this purpose, called revenuecat.  It is a paid service.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, it is possible to get a list of all transactions and their current state under 'Order Management' on the Google Play Console.  For each transaction it provides the ID, date/time, item purchased, status, $ paid.

I haven't found comparable info for iOS.  The only way to figure out about inAppPurchases is to query the app store regarding a single device (from that device).

If someone else knows a way to do what was requested in the original post, please post it.